# If Then statement never executes (VBScript)

Tags: if-statement, vbscript, hta

I just started learning HTA and VBScript on my own a few weeks ago by starting this program for work. I'm still a novice so forgive me if this is a dumb question. I've been searching for two hours and either I'm incompetent or I have no idea how to search for the question.

I need this script to check for three files; if all three exist, the script will continue, if one is missing then a dialogue box will pop up telling the user which one is missing. I have looked at what feels like fifty different ways of doing this but none of them work for me. The following method is the only one that does not return any errors, the problem is it doesn't do anything at all, it's just a blank window. (I'm testing this by only checking for one file first)

```
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

    ' Resize and center the window
    ' ==========================================================
        sub DoResize
            window.resizeTo 350,250
                screenWidth = Document.ParentWindow.Screen.AvailWidth
                screenHeight = Document.ParentWindow.Screen.AvailHeight
                    posLeft = (screenWidth - 350) / 2
                    posTop = (screenHeight - 250) / 2    
            window.moveTo posLeft, posTop
        end Sub

        DoResize()

</SCRIPT>

<TITLE>Test</TITLE> 
    <HTA:APPLICATION  
        Id="oInstall"  
        APPLICATIONNAME="Test" 
        SCROLL="no" 
        SINGLEINSTANCE="yes" 
        WINDOWSTATE="normal" 
        SELECTION="NO" 
        CONTEXTMENU = "NO" 
        BORDER="Dialogue" 
        BORDERStyle = "Normal" 
        INNERBORDER = "YES" 
        NOWRAP 
        SYSMENU = "YES" 
    > 

<HEAD> 
    <STYLE type=text/css>
    textarea {
        overflow: hidden;
        color: #ffffff;
        border: none;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    </STYLE>
    <body background="c:\mount\windows\system32\aopentools\Images\MSCBG.bmp">
</HEAD>
<textarea name="ProgSect" rows=1 cols=16 readonly></textarea><img src="c:\mount\windows\system32\aopentools\images\mscind.gif">
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript"> 

         Option Explicit

Sub Check

    ' Creating objects
    ' ==========================================================

        Dim WshShell
        Dim objFSO, outFile
        Dim filesys

        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set oFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' ==========================================================

    If oFile=oFSO.FileExists("c:\users\jgainey\desktop\test.txt") Then

        BeginImage

    Else

        MsgBox "An Error Has Occurred" & vbNewLine & "EC03: Test.txt" & vbExclamation & "ERROR"
        Window.Close

    End If

End Sub

Sub BeginImage

    ' Creating objects
    ' ==========================================================

        Dim intWindowStyle
        Dim bWaitOnReturn
        Dim objShell
        Dim WshShell
        Dim objFSO, outFile
        Dim filesys

        Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        set oFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

            set oFile=oFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\users\jgainey\desktop\test.txt",1)
                text=oFile.ReadAll
                document.all.ProgSect.value=text

End Sub

        </SCRIPT> 
    </BODY> 
</HTML>
```

The result is a window with my background image, my .gif, my text area and that's it, the text area never populates. When I remove the test.txt file no message box pops up, nothing is impacted whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set up the event so that the Sub Check runs on page load, like so:

```
<body background="c:\mount\windows\system32\aopentools\Images\MSCBG.bmp" onload="Check">
```

**Edit**

Error free implementation of the Sub Check method:

```
Sub Check

    ' Creating objects
    ' ==========================================================

        Dim oFSO
        Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' ==========================================================

    If oFSO.FileExists("c:\users\jgainey\desktop\test.txt") Then

        BeginImage

    Else

        MsgBox "An Error Has Occurred" & vbNewLine & "EC03: Test.txt" & vbExclamation & "ERROR"
        Window.Close

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: EDIT: Okay I added it and got all my variables defined, now it's just returning the message box even though the file exists.

Comment: That's strange... Double check the file location again... Also confirm that your page has permission to access the file...

Comment: Works perfectly if the text document is there, but if I move it I get the ugly old, "Error: File not found" Script Error window. Since we need to use error codes, this can't happen. Is there any way to circumvent that? Thanks again for the above, though, I'd up vote you if it would let me.

Comment: Changing the MsgBox won't make the built in Windows popup go away though.

Comment: I think you're triggering the builting windows popup somewhere else, maybe on the `BeginImage` Sub? The `FileExists` method should not throw errors...

Comment: Never mind I am a giant doofus, I forgot I changed 'BeginImage' to 'BeginBody' sorry about that. Everything is well now. Thanks for all your help you guys.

Comment: @bastos.sergio No, he can't (yet). A minimum of 15 reputation is required for this privilege.